# How to properly use models to print an elegant outcome

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've super new to CodeIgniter 3 and I'm using it to build a task manager ([Claritask.com](https://Claritask.com)). Also, I'm just starting to learn how to program, so forgive me beforehand if I'm not making sense and I'll try to clarify in comments.

As I'm building my specific Project page that lists specifc tasks, I was curious to know if I'm doing it right.

What I need on my view is: tasks belonging to a specific Project & the name of the project. I can get this to work fine, however I want to learn if my way of doing it correct.

I'm using two various methods

The first method I'm using, deals with having two functions on my Model, triggering two queries:

```
// Show project tasks
function get_tasks($project_id) {
    $this->db->from('tasks');
    $this->db->where('tasks.project_id', $project_id);
    $this->db->order_by('tasks.created_date', 'DESC');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();    
}

// Show single project name
function get_single_project($project_id) {
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $this->db->where('projects.id', $project_id);
    return $this->db->get()->row_array();   
}
```

Then on my controller

```
$data['tasks'] = $this->project_model->get_tasks($project_id);
$data['project_name'] = $this->project_model->get_single_project($project_id)['project_name'];
```

This is working as expected, and producing an elegant array (especially on projects without tasks).

```
array (
  'tasks' => 
  array (
  ),
  'project_name' => 'Default name',
)
```

However I didn't like triggering two different queries, so I decided to JOIN projects with tasks and have one hit to the database, as such:

```
// Show project tasks
function get_project_tasks($project_id) {
    $this->db->select("tasks.*, projects.project_name");
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $this->db->where('projects.id', $project_id);
    $this->db->join('tasks', 'tasks.project_id = projects.id', "LEFT");
    $this->db->order_by('tasks.created_date', 'DESC');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();    
}
```

and then my controller:

```
$data['tasks'] = $this->project_model->get_project_tasks($project_id);
$data['project_name'] = $data['tasks'][0]['project_name'];
```

While the second approach is using one query only, It's also producing an "empty" array (below) on projects without any tasks and causing to print at least one empty line within a 'foreach'.

```
array (
  'tasks' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => NULL,
      'project_id' => NULL,
      'list_id' => NULL,
      'task_text' => NULL,
      'task_due_date' => NULL,
      'created_by' => NULL,
      'created_date' => NULL,
      'project_name' => 'Website design',
    ),
  ),
  'project_name' => 'Website design',
)
```

Even though, I'm mitigating that, with the following:

```
<?php foreach($tasks as $task) { ?>
    <?php if(isset($task['id'])): ?>
        <div><?php echo $task['task_text']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Even though there are thousands of ways to skin a cat, I would like to really know which approach is the correct one: Having a specific query for each element and printing an elegant output, or optimizing the outcome.

Comment: There are a few things wrong here, but no way to give a correct answer, as this question is more of a code review, and that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: There is a [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, if you're just getting started with CI3 you might look at [Fire Starter](https://github.com/JasonBaier/ci3-fire-starter) on github, which is a great starting point and/or a source of ideas for how to implement things.

Comment: @ourmandave , I think most new users of CI suffer from not having a solid understanding of PHP and OOP. Adding Fire Starter to the confusion might be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @BrianGottier True, there's a lot there, but it's nice to see how to implement something beyond the simple CI docs examples.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @BrianGottier could you point me at least in some direction about what's wrong with my code & how to do it better? I'm checking out "Code review" suggested by "ourmandave" now

Comment: Checking "Code review" now @ourmandave! Thanks

Comment: [Cross posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173827/84718) to Code Review.